# Login to website using VB Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to pull data from a site using Macro. Below is my code. It fills up the ID and password, but does not actually log into the site. Need help to identify where is the actual error. then I can slowly work on going into the right location to extract the report.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub HRALogin()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "website" 'removed actual website due to sensitivity
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.Navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.UserName.Value = "abcdefg"
HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = "1234abcd"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "login" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "login" Then
    oHTML_Element.Click
End If
Exit For
Next

Do 
'Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

Also, set the delay after you click on login, so that it loads the page correctly and then do the rest stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If oHTML_Element.Type = "login" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next
```

is equivalent to this:

```
For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If oHTML_Element.Type = "login" Then
        oHTML_Element.Click
    End If
    Exit For
Next
```

i.e. the `Exit For` is not controlled by the `If`. That might be your problem.